# How to modify phone number from a text file then print to the terminal using Sed and Extended Regular Expression?

Tags: sed

I am trying to modify the phone number from a text file and display it the following ways using the Sed and Extended Regular Expression. I am new to Regular Expression so not sure what to do.

- The first two numbers will be in parentheses and there are underscores after the second and sixth number. For example :(04)_1234_5678
- The first number will become +61, followed by a space. For every three other digits, add a dash. For example +61 412-435-678

**phone.txt**

```
0412345678
0492669266
0458291324
0427193732
0429381912
0439201291
```

I have tried `sed 'S/04/()/_1234_5678'`

Comment: What is the expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: I gave an example in the description. I have tried using sed but I am not getting anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: So you want two seperate outputs from the same file? Once again, what have you tried thus far to address the problem? Can you add your attempt to the question even if it did not work

Comment: yes, I have tried sed 'S/04/()/_1234_5678"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed s'/\(.\(.\)\)\(\(..\)\(..\)\)\(\(.\)\(...\)\)/(\1)_\3_\6\n+61 \2\4-\5\7-\8/' input_file
(04)_1234_5678
+61 412-345-678
(04)_9266_9266
+61 492-669-266
(04)_5829_1324
+61 458-291-324
(04)_2719_3732
+61 427-193-732
(04)_2938_1912
+61 429-381-912
(04)_3920_1291
+61 439-201-291
```

or individually

```
$ sed s'/.\(...\)\(...\)\(...\)/+61 \1-\2-\3/' input_file
+61 412-345-678
+61 492-669-266
+61 458-291-324
+61 427-193-732
+61 429-381-912
+61 439-201-291
```

```
$ sed s'/\(..\)\(....\)/(\1)_\2_/' input_file
(04)_1234_5678
(04)_9266_9266
(04)_5829_1324
(04)_2719_3732
(04)_2938_1912
(04)_3920_1291
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;g;s/.(...)(...)/+61 \1-\2-/mg;x;s/(..)(....)/(\1)_\2_/mg;G' file
```

Slurp file into hold space, make a copy and format each copy in the desired format and then append one copy to the other and print.

If you desire both formats on the same line (comma separated), use:

```
sed -E 's/.*/&,&/;s/(..)(....)(....),.(...)(...)/(\1)_\2_\3,+61 \4-\5-/' file
```

Or interleaved:

```
 sed -E 's/.*/&\n&/;s/(..)(....)(.....).(...)(...)/(\1)_\2_\3+61 \4-\5-/' file
```